# Use a function to update post meta based on other post meta

Tags: functions, post-meta

No idea how to title this so feel free to edit. I set out to create a "hotness" for my posts and to do this I used the `$ratings_score` which is stored as post_meta as a number +/- and the days ago of the post which I trimmed down to just the days. I divided the ratings_score by the days to get a number which reflects the hotness of the post. I ran this function inside the loop to get the result...

```
$time_ago = human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') );
if (strtotime($time_ago) <  strtotime('1 day')) {
 $time_ago = "1";
}
$days_ago = preg_replace("/[^0-9 ]/", '', $time_ago);
$days_ago;
$ratings_score = get_post_meta($post->ID,'ratings_score',true);
$hotness = $ratings_score / $days_ago;
echo $hotness;
```

That works fine but what I really need to do is make this into a function in my functions.php and store `$hotness` as post_meta. I need it to constantly update itself aswell based on the changing of the days ago and `$ratings_score`. So then I can sort my loop by the `$hotness` meta_key. How can I do that?

Comment: what is `ratings_score` made of?

Comment: I should of added that I'm using wp_postratings which uses $ratings_score to store the +/- number of the rating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two simple ways to do this:

One is to use the `the_content`-filter to update the post "hotness", or you can schedule an event that will run daily and update the "hotness" once a day.

#### First approach: `the_content`-filter

Turn you code in to a "callable" function:

```
function update_hotness( $post_id, $echo = false ) {
    $time_ago = human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U', $post_id ), current_time('timestamp') );
    if ( strtotime($time_ago) <  strtotime('1 day') ) {
        $time_ago = "1";
    }

    $days_ago = preg_replace( "/[^0-9 ]/", '', $time_ago );
    $days_ago;
    $ratings_score = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ratings_score', true );
    $hotness = $ratings_score / $days_ago;
    // Here you store the "hotness" as post meta
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hotness', $hotness );
    if ( $echo )
        echo $hotness;
    return $hotness;
}
```

So you can now get and update the post "hotness" with this function by just passing it the post id.

Next you create a hooked function to `the_content`-filter which will update the posts "hotness" every time `the_content` is called:

```
add_filter( 'the_content','update_hotness_filter' );
function update_hotness_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;
    update_hotness( $post->ID );
    return $content;
}
```

#### Second approach: Scheduling an event

First, create a function that will check if your event is scheduled or not, then update accordingly:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'hotness_update_activation' );
function hotness_update_activation() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'daily_hotness_update' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'daily', 'daily_hotness_update' );
    }
}
```

Finally you make sure to add an action hook to your event and a function that will run every day:

```
add_action( 'daily_hotness_update', 'daily_hotness_update_callback' );
function daily_hotness_update_callback() {
    // Here you get a list of posts to update the "hotness" for.
    // Then you just call `update_hotness()` for each one ex:
    foreach ( $posts as $p ) {
        update_hotness( $p->ID );
    }
}
```

And that is it :)

If you ask me you should go with the simpler way, which is the first approach.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. This works like a charm!